# Redux - Is it okay to have actions that don't effect the sate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, redux, react-redux

Is it okay to have actions that do not effect anything in the Redux state tree?

e.g.

An async request the just responds with a HTTP code 200 or 404 ...

Comment: event 200, 404 is a state change (error handling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.
It's totally fine.

If your store is written well, it's pretty much just going to return a copy of the value it had previously.

That said, it's pretty useless to fire an event which does absolutely nothing.

The reason that Redux tutorials suggest separating actions, action-creators and the people calling the action-creators with actions, is exactly so that you can decide what gets sent to the store; there's no "click here for a 50/50 chance we're going to update the store", because it's no longer a part of the function method.

Comment: Wow okay! So I don't have to dispatch it! Great !

Comment: Redux is meant to store the state, manage the state, and update the view, based on a change to the state. If no state has changed, and your page care about the result, and the user doesn’t care about seeing new views based on the result, then there is clearly no reason to dispatch it.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "yes, it's ok" - though that's my opinion.

It keeps you open to further extending your application. For example, you could have something like:

```
export function fetch(sysId:string) {
    return function(dispatch:Function) {
        dispatch(fetching());

        $.ajax(...)
            .fail(e => dispatch(failed()))
            .done(data => dispatch(fetched(data)));
    }
}

export function failed() {
    return { type: 'SERVER/FAILED' };
}

export function fetching() {
    return { type: 'SERVER/FETCHING' };
}

export function fetched(data:Object) {
    return { type: 'SERVER/FETCHED', data };
}
```

Currently, you may have zero intention to do anything in your reducers for the `failed` or `fetching` actions.

Then you realise you need an animated loader to display. Easy, because you have these actions in place. Obviously there is the argument to *not* add anything you don't need, but I think for common pieces like this it's little overhead.

Comment: Exactly my opinion on this! Glad to hear someone else agrees

Comment: I know what you mean. I kind of think/justify it as the action is effecting the state of your application, even if your reducers don't respond to it

Answer (score 0):

What's it responding to do? Actions are really just to set Redux state, if you don't need to set state, why are you calling an action? Just perform whatever you have to do directly in your component in that case.

Comment: Yeah was also my thinking. Although I'm referring to API calls to my application server. (AJAX).

Comment: The question is what are you doing with the response? Saving it to state? Performing something and then throwing away the result? It's got to be one or the other. If it's the former, then save it to the Redux state, if it's the later, then use it in your component and throw it away.